# A rigorous statement and proof of the two-path test

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

### Background

In multivariable calculus/complex analysis, one often tries to show that a limit doesn't exist by finding two paths which yield different limits. The justification goes that if the limit exists, it must be the same along any path; hence if it is not, it doesn't exist.

On an intuitive level, I think I understand this concept. But I have never seen a rigorous justification for this method, nor what exactly constitutes a "path".

### Attempt at a solution

#### Definition/Theorem

I'm going to stick to $\mathbb{R}^2$ here, since the arguments should generalize easily.

Let $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function defined on the domain $U$, an open proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let us define a "path" in this context to be a continuous function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, parameterized by $t$.

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x_0})$ exists. Then, for any path $\gamma$ with range in $U$ and $\gamma(t_0) = \mathbf{x_0}$,

$$\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} f(\gamma(t_0)) = L. $$

In terms of $\delta$'s and $\epsilon$'s, this says that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\left|t - t_0 \right| < \delta \Rightarrow \left| f(\gamma(t)) - f(\gamma(t_0)) \right| < \epsilon. $$

#### Proof

I don't know how to prove this.

### Example

To demonstrate, I will show that the limit in example (d) from [Paul Dawkins' Calculus III notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Limits.aspx) doesn't exist. I'll follow his proof, exchanging his intuitive definition with the formal one above.

To show: $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6 + x^2}$ doesn't exist.

*Proof*: Suppose that the limit exists and is equal to $L$.

First, take the continuous path $\gamma(t) = (t, t)$ (the path $y = x$). By our theorem, we conclude that
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{t^3t}{t^6 + t^2} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} = 0 = L.$$

But instead take the path $\gamma(t) = (t, t^3)$ (the path $y = x^3$). By our theorem, we conclude that this is also equal to $L = 0$, but we have
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{t^3(t^3)}{t^6 + (t^3)^2} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{t^6}{2t^6} = \frac{1}{2},$$
which is a contradiction. Thus, the limit does not exist.

### Summary

So the definition seems to work. My questions are (1) is the definition/theorem I've stated above in terms of continuous paths the most general one and (2) how can we prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sticking to paths is a needless (but useful) particularization of the following.

**Definition:** Let $f$ and $U$ be as in the question and let $A\subseteq U$ with $A\neq \varnothing$ and $\mathbf{x_0}\in \overline {A\,}$. Define $\lim \limits_{\mathop{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}_{\large{\mathbf{x}\in A}}}\left(f\mathbf({x})\right):=\lim \limits_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}\left(f_{|A}(\mathbf{x})\right)$. The LHS is called a *sublimit* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x_0}$.

**Claim:** If $\lim \limits_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}\left(f(\mathbf{x})\right)$ exists and equals $\mathbf {y_0}$ for some $\mathbf {y_0}\in \mathbb R$, then for all $A\subseteq U$, $\lim \limits_{\mathop{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}_{\large{\mathbf{x}\in A}}}\left(f\mathbf({x})\right)$ exists and equals $\mathbf{y_0}$.

*Proof:* It's immediate. The same $\delta$ that works for $\lim \limits_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}\left(f(\mathbf{x})\right)$, trivially works for $\lim \limits_{\mathop{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}}_{\large{\mathbf{x}\in A}}}\left(f\mathbf({x})\right)$ because $A\subseteq U$. $\square$

For the particular example of paths, just let $A=\text{im}(\gamma)$.

What's useful it the contrapositive of the claim whichs claims that if there exist $A_1, A_2\subseteq U$ such that the sublimits differ (or do not exist), then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, so much simpler than I had imagined! I wonder why this is not mentioned more often in textbooks, since it is so simple. Thanks!

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius My experience with multivariable calculus literature is null (I just know my course notes). I find this very important to mention.

Comment: Theoretically this works for an arbitrary subdomain $A$, so I guess the issue one runs into is just that $\lim\limits_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x_0}} \left( f_{|A}(\mathbf{x})\right)$ may not exist depending on how $A$ is chosen? E.g., the limit exists for both $A = U \cap \mathbb{Q}$ (the rational points in $U$) and $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \mid y = x^3$ (a continuous path)?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius The answer to the question is your comment is yes. But I wouldn't say it is 'the' issue.

Answer (score 3):

A more literal proof.

The missing ingredient is convergence in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The $\delta-\epsilon$-definition there is that $\lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x}) = L$ if and only if

$$\vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0} \vert < \delta_1 \text{ implies } \vert f(\mathbf{x})  -  L\vert < \epsilon.$$

Yet for $\delta_1$ in the role of "$\epsilon$", continuity of $\gamma$ implies that there exists $\delta$ such that

$$\vert t - t_0 \vert < \delta \text{ implies } \vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0} \vert < \delta_1$$

Concatenating, 
$$\vert t - t_0 \vert < \delta \text{ implies } \vert f(\mathbf{x})  -  L\vert < \epsilon.$$

In short, continuity of $\gamma$ is what guarantees that that you're in a close-enough neighborhood of $\mathbf{x_0}$ to get whatever general estimate of closeness you get, as in @Git Gud's answer.