# Two Path Test in case of non-homogeneous functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a doubt about using Two Path Test (for checking the continuity of multi variable functions ) in case of those functions which remain non  homogenous even after substituting $y$ in terms of $x$ or vice-versa.

For example:
Even after substituting $y$ in terms of $x$, if $x$ is remaining in numerator or denominator and limit is to be found at $x$ tending to zero, then will it be correct to say that limit tends to $0$ and $\infty$ for both the cases respectively?

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? 

See if this [helps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863380/a-rigorous-statement-and-proof-of-the-two-path-test).

Comment: Even after substituting 'y' in terms of 'x,
"x" is remaining in Numerator or denominator and limit is to be found at x tending to zero, then will it be correct to say that limit tends to "0" and "Infinity" for both the cases respectively?

Comment: Please add the same details in the question so that it is complete and clear.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help